# typeError :Cannot assign to read only property 'addContactHandler' of object '#<Object>'

Tags: reactjs

[gihub link of the project trying to imitate](https://github.com/dmalvia/React_Tutorial_Contact_Manager_App) In the project he used class component in the the add contact but i have used functional component also i have added another field.
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bT4JZ.png) . previously i passed all of the props together.

this is the AddContact.js

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'

const AddContact =(props) =>{

    const [contactName, SetContactName] = useState("");
    const [contactEmail, SetContactEmail] = useState("");
    const [contactPhone, SetContactPhone] = useState("");

    const Add = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(contactName === "" || contactEmail === ""|| contactPhone === "")
        {
            alert("All fields are mandatory!!");
            return
        }
        // props.addContactHandler={contactName};//this is child and from here i want to pass data to app.js
        props.addContactHandler={contactEmail};//this is child and from here i want to pass data to app.js
        // props.addContactHandler={contactPhone};//this is child and from here i want to pass data to app.js


        SetContactName("");
        SetContactEmail("");
        SetContactPhone("");

    }
```

and this is from App.js

```
const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);

  const addContactHandler = (contact) => {
    console.log(contact);
    setContacts([...contacts, { id: Math.random()*1000, ContactEmail : props.ContactEmail, ...contact }]);
  }
```

Comment: Hi,
Firstly, please, try to better formulate your questions because it is not clear to me what your problem is. But my guess is that it is the error you wrote in the title. As you can see you are trying to assign a value to a variable declared with const which is obviously an error. The value of a const can't be changed through reassignment, and it can't be redeclared.If you want to pass data to app.js through this method you should call this method with contact as a param: props.addContactHandle(contactEmail)

Comment: yes sir that was the problem

Answer (score 0):

In react props are read only, that means you cannot reassign any value to any prop.
in code you are trying to assign prop.addContactHandler = somevalue.
This is totally invalid.
if you want to pass any value to parent component then call a method.

e.g. in App.js
const updateVal = v => {this block updates local state}

suppose you have passed this method to child component.
in child component you need to call this method as below
props.updateVal(newValue)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Props.addContactHandler is a function. So Instead of

```js
props.addContactHandler={contactEmail};
```

you need to do something like

```js
props.addContactHandler(contactEmail);
```

Comment: that has solved the doubt . Thank you vm